# NullPointerException for Mockito.spy when trying to mock an object that being created inside a method

Tags: java, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, mockito

Helllo, I'm trying to write a test for my apply function. What I wanna do is to verify that the methods
in the try catch scope are being called when executing the function.
hhere is my apply method:

```
public Target apply(Source source) throws MappingException {
    try {
      Target target = targetModelObjectFactory.create(Target.class);
      mapNameToFirstName(source, target);
      mapMailToEMail(source, target);
      mapSourceSubEntityToTargetSubEntity(source, target);
      mapPrimitiveSourceColToPrimitiveTargetCol(source, target);
      mapSubEntitiesSourceColToSubEntitiesTargetCol(source, target);
      mapSourceSubEntityFieldToSubEntityFetchedField(source, target);
      produceProducedFieldValue(target);
      setConstantFieldConstantValue(target);
      return target;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new MappingException(source, e);
    }
  }
```

here is my test for `mapMailToEMail(source, target);`

```
@Test
    
    public void TestSettingMappedMailFromSourceToTargetEMail() {

        Source mockedSource = Mockito.mock(Source.class);
        Target mockedTarget = Mockito.mock(Target.class);

        sourceToTargetMapper.mapMailToEMail(mockedSource, mockedTarget);
        Mockito.verify(mockedTarget, Mockito.times(1)).setEMail(mockedSource.getMail());
    }
```

And here is a part of my test:

```
@Test
    public void TestApply() throws MappingException, MappingOperatorCreationException, TargetModelObjectCreationException {

        Source mockedSource = Mockito.mock(Source.class);
        TargetModelObjectFactory targetModelObjectFactory = Mockito.mock(TargetModelObjectFactory.class)
        Target mockedTarget = Mockito.spy(targetModelObjectFactory.create(Target.class));
        sourceToTargetMapper.mapNameToFirstName(mockedSource,mockedTarget);
        Mockito.verify(mockedSource,Mockito.times(1)).setMail(mockedSource.getMail());
}
```

The problem that I'm having is with this part

```
Target target = targetModelObjectFactory.create(Target.class);
```

In my test I need to mock the Target object that being created inside the method, I was tryinh to use mockito.spy for this. But I keep on getting NullPointerException for it..

Is it the right approach?
What is is that I'm missing?
Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT** stackTrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mockito.Mockito.spy(Mockito.java:2034)
    at app.transcriber.example.generated.SourceToTargetMapperTest.TestApply(SourceToTargetMapperTest.java:87)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:99)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:105)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:40)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

app.transcriber.example.generated.SourceToTargetMapperTest > TestApply FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException at SourceToTargetMapperTest.java:87
1 test completed, 1 failed
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a stack trace? It makes the issue more focused and helps us identify the problem faster and more efficiently.

Comment: @Spectric Just did!

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple mapper, why on earth would you use mocks for testing that? Just call it with some input and check the output.

And if you insist: the exception is because you are trying to spy an object created by calling `targetModelObjectFactory.create(Target.class)` and `targetModelObjectFactory` is a mock already - you cannot do that, the `create` called on a mock returns `null`. Either create a real `Target` or a real `Factory`.

Answer (score 0):

if you get a nullpointer exception use Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS argument, we tell Mockito to make a kind of deep mock. This makes it possible to mock the result of a complete method.

```
<Class_Name> ref = Mockito.mock(Class_Name.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```